# How to allocate an array with a size defined by two vectors?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I want to create zeros of size defined by two vectors, which will work in 2D and 3D.

```
%% Setting in 2D
% rectangular domain with left bottom corner [_1,_2]
% and right top  corner [_1,_2]

    lb_corner=[-1,-2]
    rt_corner=[2,2]

    domain_size=rt_corner - lb_corner; 

    dim=size(domain_size,2);

    nb_pixels=[5,4]; % number of pixels in [x_1,x_2]

%% Mesh parameters
   pixel_size= domain_size./nb_pixels;

%% Coordinates

    if dim == 2
        x_coords=zeros(nb_pixels(1),nb_pixels(2),dim);
    elseif dim == 3
        x_coords=zeros(nb_pixels(1),nb_pixels(2),nb_pixels(3),dim);

    end
```

In three dimensions the vectors would look like this:,

```
%% Setting in 3D
lb_corner = [-2,-2,-2]
rt_corner = [2,2,2] 
domain_size=rt_corner - lb_corner; 

dim=size(domain_size,2); 
nb_pixels=[5,4,5]; % number of pixels in [x_1,x_2,x_3]
```

I want to replace if condition with something like:

```
%    x_coords=zeros(nb_pixels,dim);
```

this should create array of size `(nb_pixels(1),nb_pixels(2),dim)` in 2D,
and array of size `(nb_pixels(1),nb_pixels(2),nb_pixels(3),dim)`  in 3D

Comment: How is `nb_pixels` initialized if `dim ==3`? As currently written, your code will error when trying to get a nonexistent third element.

Comment: %% Setting in 3D
    lb_corner = [-2,-2,-2]
    rt_corner = [2,2,2]

    domain_size=rt_corner - lb_corner; 

    dim=size(domain_size,2);

    nb_pixels=[5,4,5]; % number of pixels in [x_1,x_2,x_3]

Comment: @MartinLadecký As you can see, comments aren't really good for more than a short line of code. You should [edit] your question to add more details. I have copied the contents of your comment to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate them and hand `zeros` the size array:

```
x_coords=zeros([nb_pixels,dim]);
```

Comment: Great! this is precisely what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Much nicer than cell arrays...